# Change Google Sign-in dialogs for Google Home

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-signin, actions-on-google, google-home

Currently I have a simple dialogflow project for Google Home which uses the [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) feature to retrieve information from a logged in user. When I start the app, Google Sign-in will ask me if I allow my app to create an account and use my information.

[image]

Is it possible to change the above placeholder text or any of the other Google Sign-in dialogs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is common language that applies to all Actions on Google.

While this is not stated explicitly in the documentation here [1], everything that is actually customizable is covered in project configuration and starting the authentication flow sections.

[1] https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in

Comment: Could you provide some documentation or links state this?